# 502 Error on Production Deployment Django & Nginx using a docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to build containers and to serve the frontend of my website at https:// example.com and the backend at a subdomain, https:// api.example.com. The SSL certificates for both the root and subdomain are working properly, and I can access the live site (static files served by Nginx) at https:// example.com so at least half of the configuration is working properly. The problem occurs when the frontend tries to communicate with the backend. All calls are met with a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" 502 Error in the console logs. In the logs of the docker container, this is the error response.

###### Docker Container Error

```
 2022/03/09 19:01:21 [error] 30#30: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting 
to upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /api/services/images/ 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services/images/", 
host: "api.example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

I think it's likely that something is wrong with my Nginx or docker-compose configuration. When setting the SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT, SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS, and the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS to False or None (in the Django settings) I am able to hit http:// api.example.com:8000/api/services/images/ and get the data I am looking for. So it is running and hooked up, just not taking requests from where I want it to be. I've attached the Nginx configuration and the docker-compose.yml. Please let me know if you need more info, I would greatly appreciate any input, and thanks in advance for the help.

###### Nginx-custom.conf

```
# Config for the frontend application under example.com
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   example.com www.example.com;
  
  if ($host = www.example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  if ($host = example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  return 404;
}

server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  index index.html index.htm;

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin      $http_origin;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers     $http_access_control_request_headers;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods     $http_access_control_request_method;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

##### Config for the backend server at api.example.com 

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  api.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name api.example.com;

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin      $http_origin;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers     $http_access_control_request_headers;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods     $http_access_control_request_method;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/; #API Server
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect  off;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

###### Docker-Compose File

```
version: '3.9'

# services that make up the development env 
services:

  # DJANGO BACKEND
  backend:
    container_name: example-backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: example-backend:1.0.1
    build:
      context: ./backend/src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    command: gunicorn example.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=xxx
      - DEBUG=0
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=example.com,api.example.com,xxx.xxx.xxx.x
      - DB_HOST=postgres-db                   
      - DB_NAME=xxx
      - DB_USER=xxx
      - DB_PASS=xxx
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASS=xxx

    # sets a dependency on the db container and there should be a network connection between the two 
    networks:
      - db-net
      - shared-network
    links:
      - postgres-db:postgres-db
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
  
  # POSTGRES DATABASE
  postgres-db:
    container_name: postgres-db
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - example-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=exampledb
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    networks:
      - db-net

  # ANGULAR & NGINX FRONTEND 
  frontend:
    container_name: example-frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - shared-network
    links:
      - backend 
    depends_on:
      - backend
 
networks:
  shared-network:
    driver: bridge
  db-net:
  
volumes:
  example-data:
```

Comment: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is telling the Nginx container to forward requests to a different port in the same container.  Do you mean to use the Compose service name `backend` as a host name here instead?  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details on how to call between containers.

Comment: I'm new to Nginx so I completely missed that, changing the proxy pass to `http://backend:8000;` fixed the connection issue and I can now hit the api.example endpoint. I still have a CORS issue with the production site, but it looks like that is just an issue with the headers or something because hitting the endpoint with Postman works just fine.

Comment: The CORS error I'm now getting is -> request blocked (Reason: Multiple CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ not allowed).

Comment: Just to follow up the CORS error looks like it was caused by the headers both being defined in the nginx file and in the django settings removing the add_header portion of the server block in the nginx configuration solved my problem. Thanks again for the help! @DavidMaze if you post your comment as the answer Ill accept it.